# Cannot destructure property of '{}' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've updated some legacy code to react 18 (from 17) and react-router-dom 6 (from v4) and for some reason I'm encountering this error on existing code (that was working just fine)

In all my components I access some data like so

```
const {
  user,
  person,
  loading,
  locale,
  building: { locale: building_locale } = {},
  updateContext,
} = useContext(GlobalContext)
```

Right here is the console of said context on his initial state, on the render I'm getting the issue below :
[image]
[image]

The code works perfectly fine if I'm doing some workaround like this

```
const {
  user,
  person,
  loading,
  locale,
  building,
  updateContext,
} = useContext(GlobalContext)
const building_locale = building?.locale
```

But those changes would impact roughly 3k files and I'm really not looking forward to having to execute that kind of regex.

As far as I know, the code is actually working fine and the error makes no sense but maybe someone has any clue as to why this might happen

I would have provided a codepen if I was somehow able to reproduce in a pristine coding environment but this seems to be specific to my app's context, mostly looking for some ideas / rubber ducks

Comment: What about using `building: { locale: building_locale } = {locale: null}`?

Comment: Tried it aswell, error is now

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'locale' of '{(intermediate value)}' as it is null.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an issue when  `building` value is null, a workaround is to declare it as `undefined` instead:

```js
const o1 = { building: { locale: undefined } };  // Works - even with null
const o2 = { building: null };  // Throws
const o3 = { building: undefined };  // Works


const testDestructuring = (obj) => {
  try {
    const { building: { locale: building_locale } = {} } = obj;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj),': Destructured with no errors');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const tests = [o1, o2, o3];
tests.forEach(testDestructuring);
```

Comment: Yeah my thoughts too but I just can't find any renders where the value is actually set to nul ; might be worth digging this hole though it's probably linked to some api's data

Comment: Yeah definitely. It doesn't seem related to react update though, could be related to react.router update, since from 4 to 6 it's twice breaking changes, and if that `building` value is somewhat related to react.router location or params object, that could be the reason since v6 does not pass anymore that data through props.